# Executing a function only once

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm using Waypoints.js to start a counter function when I scroll down the page:

```
$(".counter").waypoint(function() {
  $(".counter").count();
}, {offset:"100%"});
```

Everything works great but if I scroll up the page and down again to the counter, it starts counting all over again. How can I execute the counter function only once?

Comment: wrap it in a closure, set Boolean flag to true, check it before executing, profit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what that code is meant to do, but you can always use a flag variable to control something like that:

```
var executed = false;
$(".counter").waypoint(function() {
    if (!executed) {
        executed = true;
        $(".counter").count();
    }
}, {offset:"100%"});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this already has an accepted answer, but the current version of jQuery Waypoints, 2.x, already has this built in with the `triggerOnce` option. You don't need to manually keep a flag for if it should execute.

```
$(".counter").waypoint(function() {
  $(".counter").count();
}, {offset:"100%", triggerOnce:true});
```

This is also the same thing as calling `destroy` on the waypoint at the end of the handler so that it never executes again:

```
$(".counter").waypoint(function() {
  $(".counter").count();
  $(this).waypoint('destroy');
}, {offset:"100%"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a sentry value the first time the event fires, and skip the logic the next time based upon that.

Here's one way you could do that:

```
var count = 0;

$(".counter").waypoint(function() {
  if (count > 0) return;
  $(".counter").count();
  count++;
}, {offset:"100%"});
```

Comment: sorry, this might be really bad. I just saw your question at the top of stackoverflow. I don't know how many objects you have with the class. If you have to count per object then you could look at jquery data. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Answer (score 0):

This function does it nicely and without any additional variables or states that need to be cared for:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uje57boz/1/